# Do you have to exit blackberry simulator every single time you make a change?

Tags: blackberry-simulator

do i have to kill my simulator before i want to see the latest code changes on the sim? or is there a way of getting the BB simulator to pick up the latest code changes without having to exit the current instance and starting the simulator again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be no way to change the executable while the simulator is running, since jar file are loaded in memory.

So yes you need to kill the simulator everytime you change the code.

**Edit :** With the version 1.1 of the eclipse plugin you can now to [hot swap code on the simulator](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/04/new-code-hot-swap-feature/).

Answer (score 3):

I do a `file->Load Java Program`, `file->Reset` every compile to avoid exiting the simulator. A real device will have to reboot as well.

edit 02/28/10

from [The BlackBerry Developer](http://theblackberrydeveloper.blogspot.com/2006/08/blackberry-device-debugging-with-new.html)

> After experimenting quite a bit, and
>   posting a few questions, Mark Sohm
>   from RIM (BlackBerry Developer
>   Journal) has filled us in on the
>   conditions that an application update
>   forces a restart:
>
> 1. The application is running or the library is in use.
> 2. The application has any open resources (ie: a library could be
>      holding onto something).
> 3. The application has an active listener registered with the system.
> 4. The application has added menu items to any BlackBerry applications.
> 5. It is an auto start application.
> 6. The application is listening for incoming IO connections (this would
>      also fall under the "application is
>      running" reason).
> 7. The application makes use of persistent storage and/or
>      backup/restore features.