# View changes without restarting Blackberry simulator?

Tags: blackberry-simulator

i am using eclipse and the blackberry simulator for my BB development. is there any way of viewing your code changes without having to close the current simulator session and start a new one? it seems like it's a pain in the rear to activate a new session each and every time (just to see a code change).

Of course, if you attempt to run another instance of a simulator in eclipse, you will get a warning dialog stating that "A Blackberry debugging session is already active. Only one Blackberry debugging session can be active at one time."

thank you very much in advance,

ac

Comment: refer to this [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059067/do-you-have-to-exit-blackberry-simulator-every-single-time-you-make-a-change)

Answer (score 0):

I found this [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Hot_swap_BB_app_in_BBSS_1004166_11.jsp):

> Reload a BlackBerry device application without restarting the
>   BlackBerry Smartphone Simulator Before you begin: You must install the
>   BlackBerry® Java® SDK 5.0 or later on your computer.
>
> In Eclipse® right-click a BlackBerry device application. Complete one
>   of the following tasks: Click Run As > BlackBerry Simulator. Click
>   Debug As > BlackBerry Simulator. In the BlackBerry® Smartphone
>   Simulator, click the icon to run the application. In Eclipse, make
>   changes to the application that is running. Save the changes. Complete
>   one of the following tasks: On the Run menu, clickRun As > BlackBerry
>   Simulator. On the Run menu, click Debug As > BlackBerry Simulator. The
>   changes to the BlackBerry device application appear in the BlackBerry
>   Smartphone Simulator.

Comment: I gave it a try and it works. I used the 'Run History' option instead of 'Run As...' and changes were automatically loaded into the BB Simulator that was already running.

Answer (score 0):

I found writing a shell script to package and deploy the app with a few specific parameters was far more efficient--time-wise. Here's an example:

`"$SDKDIR/dependencies/tools/bin/blackberry-deploy" -uninstallApp -installApp -launchApp -password <your_password> -device 169.254.0.1 -package <path_to_bar_file.bar>`

I specify the shell-script to run as a build task in my IDE and and let it do it's job. The key here is the `-uninstallApp` part & `-installApp` params which saves a lot time in the long run.