# JVM exception in simple program

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator

I am writing a small demo program to display a message box in to run in blackberry. As soon as I click the OK button on the dialog, it throws me a JVM Error 104, uncaught:runtimeexception. Any help please? Here is the code :

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
public class My_First_App extends UiApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        My_First_App theApp = new My_First_App();
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }
    public My_First_App()
    {
        pushScreen(new My_First_AppScreen());
    }
}

final class My_First_AppScreen extends MainScreen
{
    public My_First_AppScreen()
    {
        super();
        HorizontalFieldManager _fieldmanager;
        _fieldmanager = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        /* declare one label to how the application title */

        LabelField applicationtitle = new LabelField("Demo",LabelField.ELLIPSIS | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);

        ButtonField _pairMe = new ButtonField("PairMe");

        FieldChangeListener listenerPairMe = new FieldChangeListener() {
            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context){
                Dialog.alert("You clicked the button!");

            }
            };


        /*set the title*/
            add(_fieldmanager);
            setTitle(applicationtitle);

        _fieldmanager.add(_pairMe);
        _pairMe.setChangeListener(listenerPairMe);



    }
    public boolean onClose()
    {
        Dialog.alert("Goodbye!");
        System.exit(0);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works perfectly, maybe you should put more information, like the version you compiled the code, which simulator you are using, and everything else that could be useful.

Comment: @Micheal B : thanks . I was using the latest simulator 9800. It seems to the problem. When I switched to 9700, it works without any Exc. Anyways, I am new to BB dev in java. So, if you don't mind, I want to keep in touch with you. I saw your profile. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It's working well on a 9800 too on my side. Are you using the latest plugin from RIM to compile ?

Comment: I guess so. I downloaded everything from RIM dev site. Anyways, I wanted it work on 9700 mainly. So not a problem. Unless I am missing something. Anyways, whenever I change some code, it is taking hell lot of time to reset and then load the program. Is there any way to run the .cod file in simulator without having to reset the simulator?

Comment: Every 5.0 simulator don't need to be closed to run a new version of your compiled App. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059067/

Answer (score 1):

create a new workspace. It's related to Eclipse, not to your code